# C program not working with errors related to C++

Tags: c++

I wrote this program for school, however I keep getting C++ related errors (apparently)

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #define int NUM_OF_CHARS 51

    void switch (char *c)
    {
        //Little Letters
        if (((*c)>=97) && ((*c)<=122))
            (*c)-=32;
        //Capital Letters
        if ((c>=65) && (c<=90))
            (*c)+=32;
        //*c>=5
        if ((c>=53) && (c<=57))
            (*c)=56;
        //*c<5
        if ((c>=48) && (c<=52))
            (*c)=48;
    }*/

    int main() {

        char string[51];
        printf("PLease Enter a String  \n");
        scanf("%s", string);
        printf("%s  =>  ", string);

        int i=0;
        char s[51];

        while((string[i]!= "\0") && (i < NUM_OF_CHARS))
           {
            s[i]=switch (string[i]);
            i++;
               }
        printf("%s", s);
        return 0;*/

    }
```

I'm getting errors like /stray xxx in program and macro names must be identified.

I'm kind of new to C so I'd appreciate if you could point me out to what the errors in this code are. Thanks!!

Comment: do you use a c compiler or a c++ compiler?

Comment: `#define int NUM_OF_CHARS 51` should just be `#define NUM_OF_CHARS 51`

Comment: C is not C++ is no C! " I keep getting C++ related errors" - So you use a C++ compiler.

Comment: You forgot the `*` before the `c` about half the time in your function.

Comment: Make sure your compiler allows `//` type comments (`-std=c11` or `-std=c99` on the command line if you use `gcc`).

Comment: _stray xxx_ isn't a c++ related error.

Comment: WHat does the actual error say? Also you have `*/` in a couple of places which can't be right

Comment: There are many typos and much confusion between chars and char pointers. But what is this `s[i] = switch` supposed to do ? Your `switch` function is a `void` function, it doesn't return anything..

Comment: I'm guessing the `//*` isn't interpreted the way he thinks it should be.

Comment: Please do not use magic numbers: `if ((c>=65) && (c<=90))` ==> `if ((*c>='A') && (*c<='Z'))`. Better would be `if(isupper(*c)) *c = tolower(*c);` or even just `*c = tolower(*c);` since only uppercase letters are converted.

Comment: The logic of your `switch` function is wrong too (hint use the `else` keyword. Also don't use magic numbers (instead of `65` write `'A'` etc.)

Comment: I have "fixed" your code, though I will be suing for mental damages. The code is still rubbish, and if I were you i'd use it as a reference to just try and re write the code without thinking about pointers. ["working" code](https://ideone.com/VPYAuV)

Comment: BTW, none of the errors have anything to do with C++ and this q should be tagged as C.

Comment: Show. Us. Your. Errors.

Comment: @George: Only if it's being compiled as C. If it's being compiled as C++, then it's a C++ question ... though without a single C++-specific idiom in it, I agree.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues. You probably want the program below. The code compiles and works but it is still absolutly horrible, but it respects your intention.

Try to make it better.

BTW the characters contained in the `string` variable are also changed, is this intended ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_OF_CHARS 51    // removed "int"

char switchcase (char *c)  // << we need to return a char not void
{                          // << name changed to switchcase
  //  all c changed to (*c), BTW: *c without () would be OK too

  //Little Letters
  if (((*c) >= 97) && ((*c) <= 122))
    (*c) -= 32;
  //Capital Letters
  else if (((*c) >= 65) && ((*c) <= 90))
    (*c) += 32;
  //*c>=5
  else if (((*c) >= 53) && ((*c) <= 57))
    (*c) = 56;
  //*c<5
  else if (((*c) >= 48) && ((*c) <= 52))
    (*c) = 48;

  return *c;
}

int main() {

  char string[51];
  printf("PLease Enter a String  \n");
  scanf("%s", string);
  printf("%s  =>  ", string);

  int i = 0;
  char s[51];

  while ((string[i] != '\0') && (i < NUM_OF_CHARS))
  {
    s[i] = switchcase(&string[i]);
    i++;            //^ & was missing here
  }

  s[i] = '\0';                   // << you forgot the zero terminator
  printf("%s", s);
  return 0;                      // << removed stray "*/"
}
```

Comment: The numbers should be replaced by character literals.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sure, but as I've written in the answer, _the code is still absolutely horrible_, and there is still a lot more to improve.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define int NUM_OF_CHARS 51
```

replace it with

```
#define NUM_OF_CHARS 51
```

also, you have used

```
void switch (char *c)
```

since switch is a keyword, you cannot use it as a function name.

Answer (score 0):

switch is a reserved word and cannot be used as a function name.

Comment: this and some `*/` where they should not be

Comment: took them off, still not running (keep getting these errors)